# Browse file and get absolute path using CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am using Cefsharp v63.0.3 NuGet package, in C# Windows Form App, I have a file upload button (HTML form input type file). I need the absolute path of the browsed file from file upload button using CefSharp. After looking some articles I found "IDialogHandler" work with file uploading but I am confused how to achieve my goal with this. Please help me out.

Form1.cs

```
public void InitializeChromium()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");

        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("localhost/myproject/index.html");

        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);

        chromeBrowser.DialogHandler = new TempFileDialogHandler();

        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

TempFileDialogHandler.cs

```
    public class TempFileDialogHandler : IDialogHandler
    {
         public bool OnFileDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefFileDialogMode mode, string title, string defaultFilePath, List<string> acceptFilters, int selectedAcceptFilter, IFileDialogCallback callback)
          {
              //callback.Continue(selectedAcceptFilter, new List<string> { Path.GetRandomFileName() });

              return true;
          }
      }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IDialogHandler_OnFileDialog.htm

Comment: `return true` , display your own file dialog on the `UI Thread`, get the file path then execute the callback.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but after click on button, app screen got blank.

Comment: Update the question to include the code you used.

Comment: Please check code part

Comment: Where are you showing your own dialog? Show your own `Dialog` on the `UI` thread then execute the callback when you have the result.

Comment: <input type="file" name="import-file" id="fileImport">

Sorry for my silliness, but how do I bind callback after this input tag, displays Dialog. By code background I am a PHP Developer, So, having trouble with C#. Please help me out.

Comment: You can cast `browserControl` to `ChromiumWebBrowser` and call `BeginInvoke` to access the `UI Thread`. Do your own research on how to open a `File Dialog` and get the result. Then execute the callback. You'll need to at least make an attempt.